# Prove that q leads to r or p

Tags: logic

Given that `p↔(r∧q)` is false,and that `r→~p` is true.
Prove that `q→(p∨r)` is always true

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  At this site we are always looking for people to try and show their work o that we can give pointed replies. We really don;t like people just posting a question and expecting us to just give the answer.  So: What have you tried yourself?  Can you please add that to your post?

Comment: Also: *How* are you supposed to show this?  Truth-table? Formal proof? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p\Leftrightarrow (r\wedge q)$ is false, exactly one of $p$ and $r\wedge q$ is false. Since $r\Rightarrow \neg p$ is true, if $p$ is true, then $r$ is false. If $p$ is false, then $r$ can be true or false.

Consider when $p$ is true. Then $q\Rightarrow p\vee r$ is true.

Consider when $p$ is false. Then $r\wedge q$ is true, so $r$ and $q$ are both true. Therefore, $q\Rightarrow p\vee r$ is true.